# php and mysql code

Tags: php, sql

I have checked and rechecked my code for a tutorial that I am doing, and I still cannot figure out what is wrong with it. A bit of help would be appreciated.

I am building a page that processes the form data from another page. The part of the markup that I am having trouble with is below.

```
<pre>
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Process the form

$subject_id = $_GET["subject"];            
$pageName =  $_POST["pageName"];
$pagePosition = $_POST["pagePosition"];
$pageVisible = $_POST["pageVisible"];
$pageContent =  $_POST["pageContent"];

if (!empty($errors)) {
$_SESSION["errors"] = $errors;
redirect_to("new_page.php");
}

$query  = "INSERT INTO pages ( subject_id, menu_name, position, visible, content ) VALUES      ('{$subject_id}' , {$pageName}, {$pagePosition} ,{$pageVisible} ,{$pageContent} )";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result) {
// Success
$_SESSION["message"] = "Page created.";
redirect_to("manage_content.php");
} else {
// Failure
$_SESSION["message"] = "Page creation failed.";
redirect_to("new_page.php?subject={$subject_id}");
}

</pre>
```

I have checked out the page that submits to the form processing page and the form submits correctly. I've also checked all the external functions that I reference and all of them work. Additionaly, the first variable that uses the $_GET superglobal works just fine. The problem is in the query somehow not being able to pull in the 4 $_POST variables. If I substitute all the variable values with hard-code values, the query goes through fine and creates a new row in my table. 
Any help with this would be appreciated, as I have checked and rechecked this so many times, and I am sure I'm missing something very small, but it's driving me crazy.
Thanks.

Comment: you're missing the quotes in the SQL around the variables, plus you should be using prepared statements if you're already using MySQLi. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and XSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your string values:

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO pages ( subject_id, menu_name, position, visible, content ) VALUES      ('{$subject_id}' , '{$pageName}', {$pagePosition} ,{$pageVisible} ,'{$pageContent}' )";
```

This would have been obvious if you checked for errors using `mysqli_error()`.

Comment: Or if he would be using prepared statements.

Comment: +1 If you are learning you should be using all the error reporting you can get your hands on!